# Implementing a graph with multiple parents and children

Tags: java, data-structures, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

I need to implement a tree-like data structure where each node has multiple parents and children and therefore multiple roots.

New nodes will only be added to the tree with as either a root with no parents or a child of one or more parents.

Nodes will not start with children, but any existing node can gain another child node with any number of other parent nodes

[image: tree example]

Comment: It looks like you're on your way to implementing this yourself - good work!  But if you need more information about what you can do with your tree-not-a-tree - consider reading about _graph_ data structures, which is what this is.  (There are multiple ways to implement a graph, they each have their pros and cons.)

Comment: This is a graph, not a tree. If you want to preserve the distinction between "parent" and "child" then it is a directed graph. If you want to preserve the property that no node is an ancestor or descendant of itself, then it is a directed acyclic graph. It's better to use the proper terminology so that people will understand your question, but also so that you can search for existing solutions more easily. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that my tree is a not a tree but a graph. A directed acyclic graph with multiple roots is exactly what I am trying to implement, and I didn't realize this was not a tree.

Comment: No problem. I added some tags which might help people find your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a `Node` class and `Graph` class. I gave each `Node` a `List<Node>` of their parent and child nodes.

Each `Node` keeps track of its own direct children and parents.

Node implementation

```
public class Node<T>{
    private T data;
    private List<Node<T>> parents;
    private List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<>();//this can be initialized because a node will not start with children
    public Node(T data){//adding a node without parents
        this.data = data;
        parents = new ArrayList<>();//make parents an empty ArrayList so other methods won't break with a null value
    }
    public Node(T data, List<Node<T>> parents){//adding a node with parents
        this.data = data;
        this.parents = parents;
    }

    //search methods
    public List<Node<T>> getChildren(){return children;}//return only direct children
    public List<Node<T>> getChildren(int level){return getChildren(new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(this)),new ArrayList<>(),level);}//convenience method to find only this node's children to a certain level
    public List<Node<T>> getChildren(List<Node<T>> find, List<Node<T>> found, int level){//level can be -1 to search through all children or a positive integer to only search the first n level of children.
        if(level!=0){//setting level to -1 will never stop the search until all children have been found because level only goes down, because the level will never reach zero
            for(Node<T> node:find){//can find the children of multiple nodes
                if(node.hasChild()) {
                    for (Node<T> child : node.getChildren()) {
                        if (!found.contains(child)) {//trees can intersect, so the child may have already been found, so only add if it hasn't
                            found.add(child);
                        }
                    }
                    getChildren(node.getChildren(),found,level--);//recursively find the remaining children of the current node
                }
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
    //a method that finds parents can be implemented by modifying the getChildren() methods

    //examples of other methods that can be added
    public T getData(){return data;}
    public boolean hasChild(){return children.size()>0;}
    void addChild(Node<T> node){children.add(node);}
    void addChildren(List<Node<T>> nodes){children.addAll(nodes);}
    public List<Node<T>> getParents(){return parents;}
    public boolean hasParent(){return parents.size()>0;}
    void addParent(Node<T> node){parents.add(node);}
    void addParent(List<Node<T>> nodes){parents.addAll(nodes);}
}
```

The `Graph` class is only used for keeping track of the graph's roots. A root is simply a `Node` with no parents. The scopes of each method can be adjusted for your specific use case. This class is meant to be extended by a more specific class that includes methods for dealing with your specific data type.

Graph implementation:

```
public class Graph<T> {
    private List<Node<T>> roots;
    protected Tree(List<Node<T>> roots){this.roots = roots;}//Graph class can be initialized with or without existing roots 
    protected Tree(){roots = new ArrayList<>();}
    public List<Node<T>> getRoots(){return roots;}
    public List<Node<T>> getAllNodes(){
        List<Node<T>> nodes = roots.get(0).getChildren(roots,new ArrayList<>(),-1);//loop through all roots with an empty list for nodes already found, because no nodes have been found yet
        nodes.addAll(roots);
        return nodes;
    }
    public void addNode(Node<T> node){
        for(Node<T> parent:node.getParents()){//for each parent node add this node as their child
            parent.addChild(node);
        }
        if(!node.hasParent())roots.add(node);
    }
    public void addNodes(List<Node<T>> nodes){
        for(Node<T> node:nodes){
            addNode(node);
        }
    }
}
```

When adding a new `Node` with parents, the `Graph` class gets the parents and adds the `Node` as a child of those parents so the parent nodes know they have child node.